# Why did Shimshon not suspect Delilah of betraying him?

Tags: shoftim--book-of, shimshon-samson

Shalom.

I have been troubled by the story of Shimshon and Delilah since I first heard it as a child.

Why did Shimshon not suspect Delilah of betraying him long before he was finally captured? Three times he found himself bound in exactly the way he had told Delilah he could be subdued!

Are we supposed to believe Shimshon was just a lovestruck fool, or was there something darker going on here (i.e. sado-masochism)?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Gemara in [Sotah 9b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sotah.9b.15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) states:

> *The verse states: “And it came to pass afterward, that he loved a woman in the valley of Sorek, whose name was Delilah” (Judges 16:4). It is taught in a baraita that Rabbi Yehuda HaNasi says: Even if she had not been called by the name Delilah, it would have been fitting that she be called Delilah, for she weakened [dildela] his strength, she weakened his heart, and she weakened his deeds, thereby decreasing his merits.* (Sefaria translation and notation)

So it would seem that Delilah had a strong influence on him that proved detrimental to Shimson's physical, emotional and spiritual faculties.

Interestingly, the [Ben Yehoyada](https://www.sefaria.org/Sotah.9b.15?lang=bi&p2=Ben_Yehoyada_on_Sotah.9b.4&lang2=bi) writes:

> דִילְדְּלָה אֶת כֹּחוֹ, דִּילְדְּלָה אֶת לִבּוֹ, דִּילְדְּלָה אֶת מַעֲשָׂיו (שופטים טז, יח). פירש הרב עיון יעקב ז"ל לשון דלות ועוני. ונראה טעם בזה כיון שהלך אחר עין שלו בדרך הפכפך הפך הדין נהפכו לו אותיות עין לאותיות עני שנעשה עני ודל בשלשה אלה.
>
> ונקיט ג' דברים **מַ**עֲשָׂיו **כֹּ**חוֹ **לִ**בּוֹ דראשי תיבות שלהם 'מלך' כי הוא היה שופט שהוא במקום מלך באותו זמן והיא דלדלה אותו בשלשה דברים הרמוזים בשם המעלה והשררה שלו וזה היה לו בשלשה דברים הנזכר מפני שהלך אחר מראה עיניו שיש בהם שלשה גוונים לבן וירוק ושחור.
> ובני ידידי כבוד הרב יעקב נר"ו פירש בשביל שזאת היתה אשה שלישית לכך דלדלה אותה בשלשה עד כאן דבריו נר"ו.
>
> ***She weakened (דִילְדְּלָה - 'Dildelah') his strength, she weakened his heart and she weakened his deeds*** - *The Rav explain in Iyun Yaakov that (the term 'dildelah') is an expression of making poor and impoverished. And it appears that the reason is because since he followed after his eye - 'ayin' in a (literal. upside down) fickle way, the judgement of his was also equally turned upside down. Thus the letters of "עין" ("eye") can be rearranged / turned upside down to read "עני" ("poor"), since she made him in poor in these areas.*
>
> *And it mentions three things (that she weakened him in)- "**מַ**עֲשָׂיו **כֹּ**חוֹ **לִ**בּוֹ" - "his deeds, his strength and his heart", and the roshei teivos (the first letter of each word) can be arranged to spell "מלך" - "King", and his role was that of judge which was in place of a king at that time, and she weakened him in three areas where he lost his sense of virtue and dominion. And it was to him in these three things that we mentioned because he went after the sight of his eyes which have three shades - white and green and black*.

So it would be fair to say that Delilah was quite a wily personality that Shimshon was besotted with, and she was able to systematically strip him away of these three previously, strong character defining traits.

Comment: Hi @tomw - if you feel this answers the question, feel free to click the tick button :-)